# get mysql count of id in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, csv

I am trying to get count of column **user_Id** using `count(user_Id)` from **mysql** as follows:

```
 count=$(mysql -uroot -proot csv_imports -e "select count(user_Id) from test_data where user_Id=\"12345\";")
```

I am not getting what is wrong with it. I want it's **numeric** result. What could help me?

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?  An error?  An incorrect value?

Comment: I am not getting any error or any result. As son as i run my **.sh** file, nothing happens. Cursor keeps blinking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using options `-B` `-N` in command `mysql`

`--batch, -B` - Print results using tab as the column separator, with each row on a new line. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.

`--skip-column-names, -N` - Do not write column names in results.

```
count=$(mysql -uroot -proot csv_imports -B -N -e "select count(user_Id) from test_data where user_Id=\"12345\";»)
```

without options `-B -N` result is:

```
+----------------+
| count(user_id) |
+----------------+
|              4 |
+----------------+
```

with option `-B` result is:

```
count(user_id)
4
```

with option `-B -N` result is:

```
4
```